# Check value of the mustache variable in helper

Tags: mustache, mustache.php

I've JSON with the price and currency name, like this:

```
[{"price": 123, "currency": "RUR"},
{"price": 456, "currency": "USD"},
{"price": 789, "currency": "EUR"}]
```

Also, i use Mustache.php to render them.
    {{price}} {{currency}} 
as template and get:
    123 RUR
    456 USD
    789 EUR

But, I want to replace "RUR", "USD", "EUR" to "Russian rubles", "US dollars", "Euro" and get

```
123 Russian rubles
456 US dollars
789 Euro
```

I think, that i can use helper

```
$mustache->addHelper('_curstyle', function($text) {
if ($text == "RUR") {return ("Russian rubles")};
if ($text == "USD") {return ("US dollars")};
if ($text == "EUR") {return ("Euro")};
});
```

but **$text equal "{{currency}}"**. And I can't use **if** construct.  How I can convert {{currency}} to value, or prerender it to use in equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Mustache.php v2.1, you can use the LambdaHelper passed as an optional second argument to your helper for rendering the original block body:

```
$mustache->addHelper('_curstyle', function($text, $mustache) {
    switch($mustache->render($text)) {
        case 'RUR':
            return 'Russian rubles';
        case 'USD':
            return 'US dollars';
        case 'EUR':
            return 'Euro';
        default:
            return $text;
    }
});
```